# How to remove/delete/modify XML elements from an XML document using Golang without using structs

Tags: xml, go

I am using Golang for an API gateway and we need to remove certain XML elements from documents.

We are unable to use structs/marshalling as the XML structures are huge and variable - but we consistently need to remove a few XML elements based on their name/path

I have tried to "walk" the XML document and "skip" certain elements based on their name.

My example is here, but I am getting errors: https://go.dev/play/p/LJtlYXWvJ_d

`panic: xml: end tag </age> does not match start tag <person>`

I must be doing something wrong, and most examples I can find use Structs to do this.

Comment: You don't need "parent" nor "skip", just start another loop: https://go.dev/play/p/6XkXcdGT4Wu

Comment: @mkopriva using another loop is a good suggestion - but using the end tag name as the point at which to stop is prone to errors if there is a nested element of the same name - https://go.dev/play/p/NF7Vh_lLG-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this output:

```
End Tag of  age  parent name is  age
```

It gives a good clue.  Then look right here:

```
        case xml.EndElement:
            println("End Tag of ", t.Name.Local, " parent name is ", parent.Name.Local)
            if skip && t.Name == parent.Name {
                skip = false
                parent = xml.StartElement{}
            }
            if !skip {
                println("Encoding End Element ", t.Name.Local, " buffer is ", buf.String())
                err := encoder.EncodeToken(token)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
            encoder.Flush()
```

From the output we can see that `skip && t.Name == parent.Name` will be true.  We toggle `skip` to be `false` and reset `parent`.  Then we proceed to check `if !skip` .  We just set `skip` to false, so we attempt to encode the token.  But we were supposed to skip that token!

[The fix is simple](https://go.dev/play/p/HX-1krwHmiH): just add a `break` to that case condition.

```
            if skip && t.Name == parent.Name {

                skip = false
                parent = xml.StartElement{}
                break
            }
```

gives (debugging output removed):

```
&#x9;&#x9;<people>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;<person>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;<name>John</name>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;</person>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;<person>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;<name>Jane</name>
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;
&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;</person>
&#x9;&#x9;</people>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use skipping based on stopping when the end tag name matches the start tag name - as this is prone to errors as soon as the skipped element contains a nested element of the same name.

Use depth of elements instead, e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    xmlStr := `<people xmlns="foo.com">
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <age><age>35</age></age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jane</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </person>
</people>`
    r := strings.NewReader(xmlStr)
    w := new(bytes.Buffer)
    skipCheck := func(elem xml.StartElement) bool {
        return elem.Name.Local == "age"
    }
    if err := stripTransform(r, w, skipCheck); err == nil {
        println(w.String())
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func stripTransform(r io.Reader, w io.Writer, skipCheck func(elem xml.StartElement) bool) error {
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(r)
    encoder := xml.NewEncoder(w)
    var err error
    var token xml.Token
    depth := 0
    skip := func(to int) {
        var skipToken xml.Token
        for err == nil && depth >= to {
            skipToken, err = decoder.RawToken()
            switch skipToken.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                depth++
            case xml.EndElement:
                depth--
            }
        }
    }
    for err == nil {
        token, err = decoder.RawToken()
        if err == nil {
            switch tt := token.(type) {
            case xml.StartElement:
                if skipCheck(tt) {
                    skip(depth)
                } else {
                    depth++
                    err = encoder.EncodeToken(token)
                }
            case xml.EndElement:
                depth--
                err = encoder.EncodeToken(token)
            default:
                err = encoder.EncodeToken(token)
            }
        } else if err == io.EOF {
            err = nil
            break
        }
    }
    if err == nil {
        err = encoder.Flush()
    }
    return err
}
```

[try on go-playgound](https://go.dev/play/p/F3mmNJ8qbYH)